# No Code Signing Identities Found With Xcode Server Bot While Making .ipa

Tags: xcode, testflight, provisioning-profile, osx-server, xcode-bots

Ways tried:Export Certificate and add in following directory /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Keychains
[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: The machine running Xcode server needs to have the key - cert pair for distribution in its Keychain.  And then the provision profile built from that cert needs to be on that machine as well

Comment: @bolnad the certificates are in keychain and provisioning profile are machine as well,still getting this error.While making archive it is running well,but when i want to make .ipa with xcode-bot it is throwing error

Comment: @Diksha the cert and key pair need to be together, u need both and they need to be in system area of keychain.  If that's ok then check your code signing setting to make sure those are setup to pull the correct provision against the right code signer

Comment: @bolnad both cert and provisioning is in system area only of keychain and  if it is working fine while archiving ,why am getting error while integration with bot.

Answer (score 0):

If u get this error,u can solve it by following below steps:-

1. Make a temporary copy of the keychain on our desktop: sudo cp /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Keychains/Portal.keychain ~/Desktop/

   2. Change the permissions so we'll be able to open it: sudo chown [username]:staff ~/Desktop/Portal.keychain (replacing [username] with your own)
   3. Use the shared secret to change the password to something temporary (this will prompt you for a new password):security set-keychain-password -o "`sudo cat /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/SharedSecrets/PortalKeychainSharedSecret`" ~/Desktop/Portal.keychain
   4. Open Portal.keychain in Keychain Access
   5. Unlock it
   6. Add your certificates (and their private keys) to Portal
   7. Re-lock it
   8. Restore the original password: security set-keychain-password -p "`sudo cat /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/SharedSecrets/PortalKeychainSharedSecret`" ~/Desktop/Portal.keychain
   9. Reset permissions: sudo chown _xcsbuildd:_xcs ~/Desktop/Portal.keychain
   10. Replace the original keychain: sudo cp ~/Desktop/Portal.keychain /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Keychains/
   11. Reboot server, then integrate again.

These steps made my day...:)